# Change Arial to some other font on the whole webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm thinking about a script that can change a webpage's font appearance from **Arial** to some other font face of my choice.

How should I go about doing that?

I understand: `* { font-family: "SomeFont"; }`

But this won't achieve the objective to only target **Arial** text.

I can use jQuery or Javascript, whichever is more efficient and fast.

**Edit:** Seems like people have difficulty understanding the question. So I'll explain some more, I just want the **Arial** text on the webpage, ***if*** it ***exists***, to change in appearance.

Comment: jQuery === Javascript

Comment: What's this for? You know, `Arial` may not even be available in the user's system...

Comment: @Andreas `$(this)` != JavaScript ;)

Comment: @roxon, he uses triple `=` to depict that not only jQuery is Javascript, but their types are equal to. I hope he's trolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to suggest looping through the [`styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.styleSheets) array and, for each style sheet, loop through the rules, find the ones defining `Arial` as the font, and change that to the other font you want. That way you wouldn't have to visit every element on the page.

The problem with that suggestion, though, is inline styles on elements.

So I hate to say, to do this you'll have to visit every element on the page. For most pages, that won't be a problem, but your mileage may vary.

Here's how you'd do it with jQuery:

```
$("*").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.css("font-family").toLowerCase().indexOf("arial") !== -1) {
        $this.css("font-family", "SomeOtherFont");
    }
});
```

Can't say I like it, though. :-) You can avoid building the massive list (`$("*")` builds a jQuery object containing **all** of the page elements, which can be quite large) at the outset if you do a recursive walk instead, e.g.:

```
$(document.body).children().each(updateFont);
function updateFont() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.css("font-family").toLowerCase().indexOf("arial") !== -1) {
        $this.css("font-family", "SomeOtherFont");
    }
    $this.children().each(updateFont);
}
```

That may be preferable, you'd have to profile it.

Doing it without jQuery would involve recursively looping through the `childNodes` of each element and using either [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) (most browsers) or [`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (IE) to get the font information, then (if necessary) assigning to `element.style.fontFamily`.

---

Actually, a "both and" solution would probably be best. First, update the stylesheets, and then walk the tree to catch any inline styles. That way, presumably you'll get most of them by changing the stylesheets, which avoid the ugliness of the piecemeal update. Also, you don't have to use `css()` (jQuery) or `getComputedStyle` / `currentStyle` (without jQuery), you can just check `element.style.fontFamily`, so it would be more efficient.

Beware that IE's stylesheet object uses an array called `rules`, others use `cssRules`, but other than that they are largely the same.

Comment: I agree disliking, I'd rather replace the fonts in stylesheet. This and other solutions will lead to an ugly font replacements live on page

Comment: Yes, I see your point. It seems to be the only way. I'm gonna mark this as the right answer in the next 5 minutes. If other people aren't able to come up with something good.

Comment: @JonathanMcIntyre theres no such good thing like massive styles replacements AFAIK

Comment: @JonathanMcIntyre: Actually, a "both and" solution might be best. First update the stylesheets, then walk the tree to catch any inline styles. That way you're probably doing a lot fewer inline updates and the changes won't be quite so apparent.

Comment: issue example some font styles differ from height, now let's say you followed a hash link, the page will lead you to it and at some point JS / jQ will change the font style creating an ugly 'jump'

Comment: @roXon it shouldn't be a problem, do #jumps work by taking font-face height into account as well? I thought the algorithm is just to search for the div/block and move the scroll-caret so that it's visible to the user.

Comment: @JonathanMcIntyre: I think he means if he change happens *after* the page is loaded. So, user follows link `example.html#foo`, browser scrolls to where `#foo` is on the page, JavaScript kicks in to update the fonts, and now `#foo` is in a slightly different place (but the scroll position isn't updated). Following links after the font update will be fine. It's not likely to be a *big* issue, but it's there. I'm sure you already know the ideal solution would be to avoid having to do this (by changing the source of the Arial), but I figure you would have done that if it were an option. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, will regressively test it with this scenario. Will see what can be done if it's really an issue that I can be bothered to resolve. Btw, I LOLd at your last sentence. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to change only Arial using @font-face.

First link to a css:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fonts/luxi-Sans-fontfacekit/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
```

Then in your css refine what Arial is:

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    src: url('luxisr-webfont.eot');
    src: url('luxisr-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('luxisr-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('luxisr-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('luxisr-webfont.svg#LuxiSansRegular') format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Arial';
   src: url('luxisb-webfont.eot');
   src: url('luxisb-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('luxisb-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('luxisb-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('luxisb-webfont.svg#LuxiSansBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Only Arial is changed (in my example to Luxi Sans).  All other fonts remain as usual.